# GAE Datastore date is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

Im trying to send a the 10 latest post from an datastore in app engine.

This is the database:

```
class Author(ndb.Model):
    """Sub model for representing an author."""
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

class Message(ndb.Model):
    """A main model for representing an individual Message entry."""
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is the code:

```
class Query(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        message_name = self.request.get('db_name',
                                         DEFAULT_KEY)
        message_query = Message.query(ancestor=db_key(
                                      message_name)).order(-Message.date)
        messages = message_query.fetch(10)

        items = [] 

        for message in message_query:
            items.append({'id': message.author.identity, 
                          'email':message.author.email,
                          'content':message.content,
                          'date':message.date})    


        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(items))
```

And the error-message:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 21, 15, 43, 58, 248650) is not JSON serializable
```

Why cant JSON return the date on that format?
And how do i re-format it to the correct JSON format?

Br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the [JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) class to handle any object type, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

import json

class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
   def default(self, obj):
      if isinstance(obj, datetime):
         # format however you like/need
         return obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
      # pass any other unknown types to the base class handler, probably
      # to raise a TypeError.   
      return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


objDict = {"str":"foo", "int":212, "date":datetime.today()}

print json.dumps(objDict, cls=MyJsonEncoder)

{"int": 212, "date": "2015-03-21", "str": "foo"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, I would recommend installing and using the ndb_json.py module at https://gist.github.com/erichiggins/8969259 -- it robustly and elegantly takes case of all sorts of potential traps and pitfalls on your behalf.  Then, `ndb_json.dumps` is all you need.

Note, though, a peculiar anomaly in the code you post...:

```
    message_query = Message.query(ancestor=db_key(
                                  message_name)).order(-Message.date)
    messages = message_query.fetch(10)

    items = [] 

    for message in message_query:
        items.append(...)
```

This will fetch the newest 10 messages into the `messages` list, which you then completely ignore!, and then all **older** messages (from looping on the query) get put into `items` in unbounded numbers.  I somehow doubt this is actually what you want -- maybe you meant the `for` to be:

```
    for message in messages:
        items.append(...)
```

to serialize into the response "just the newest 10 messages" rather than "all messages **except** the newest 10" which is what your code does.

So, if this is the case, with the module I recommend you'd avoid all the "building of `items`" part, and just replace

```
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(items))
```

with

```
self.response.write(ndb_json.dumps(messages))
```

(note also that the `out` part is a legacy artifact/hack for backwards compatibility with ancient versions of `webapp` and best not used in new apps -- not directly related to your Q but, just like for what I believe is the bug you may have in serializing "the rest of the query" rather than "the newest 10 messages", hopefully helpful to you!-)

Answer (score 1):

JSON knows nothing about the datetime objects. It depends on what you want to to with the time later. I would recommend you to convert it to a unix timestamp, which is just an integer and therefore JSON serializable.

Here is a post where the conversion of datetime objects into integers is described for all python versions: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python)